How to disable the logging of 404 errors in production?
My production Nuxt3 app logs all 404 caused by bots. I get several hundreds of these messages:
13|fronten |{
13|fronten |   url: '//blog/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml',
13|fronten |   statusCode: 404,
13|fronten |   statusMessage: 'Page not found: //blog/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml',
13|fronten |   message: 'Page not found: //blog/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml',
13|fronten |   stack: '',
13|fronten |   data: '{"path":"//blog/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml"}'
13|fronten | }

This seems to be a H3 thing. How can I disable it?

Not sure it is good practice to disable logging, especially on production. But if you wanna continue this path, here is a good start IMO.

Yeah I had found this already, but it does not solve my problem - I want to keep logging other errors than 404. The sheer amount of 404 is obfuscating the "real" errors

Can't you put some filtering on the errors you're receiving? Why does it not help you? Give quite some leads to customize the logging further.
